# Polymer app-location not working

Tags: routes, polymer-2.x, app-route

i'm trying a very simple routing, yet unable to get it work. My code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="lab1-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <app-location route="{{rt}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
      route="{{rt}}"
      pattern="/:view"
      data="{{rd}}"
      tail="{{tail}}"
    ></app-route>
    <iron-pages selected="[[rd.view]]" attr-for-selected="pgid" fallback-selection="404" >
        <h2 pgid="profile">Profile</h2>
        <h2 pgid="detail">Detail</h2>
        <h2 pgid="form">Form</h2>
        <h2 pgid="404">404</h2>
    </iron-pages>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class Lab1App extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'lab1-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        // console.log(dataRute);
        return {};
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(Lab1App.is, Lab1App);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

i'm not sure what part is wrong, i can tell iron-pages is working since it always show 404,

but when i tried to load `localhost:8081/detail`, it still show 404. any help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with the implementation, i forgot to import `<app-location>` in my index.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
```

yes, silly mistake. sorry stackoverflow for taking your disk space